# Microsoft Band SDK Deploy Error: To ARM in Release: Raw error code: 2148733978

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, microsoft-band

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy an app with the Microsoft Band SDK. The build config is RELEASE and the target output is ARM. If use DEBUG config, it works.

```
Error : DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 2001.
```

I've examined the MDILXapCompileLog and the following is the where the compilation failed:

```
CrossGen failed 
Error processing assembly [projectpath]...\obj\ARM\Release\MSIL\Microsoft.Band.dll
Raw error code: 2148733978
```

NOTE: The extra weird part about this situation is that if I only package the app without deploying, I can side-load it to the device and it works as expected.

Here are the csproj sections - Debug/ARM:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<OutputPath>bin\ARM\Debug\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_PHONE_APP</DefineConstants>
<NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
<UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
```

Release/ARM

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
<OutputPath>bin\ARM\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_PHONE_APP</DefineConstants>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
<UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
```

The only difference I see are the debug symbols, could the Microsoft.Band.dll not have public symbols? Isn't Visual Studio supposed to created them?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the whole solution in debug mode (build menu -> Rebuild Solution), and see if it still works?

Comment: Yep, everything works fine in debug. Done rebuilds, changed configurations, etc. I've even tried manually deleting bin/obj folders and rebuilt all to make sure there were no lingering DLLs interfering.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with my project although not including the Band SDK. Every dll the app uses seems to cause this problem, just started happening recently and there seems to be no common fi or any real explanation.

Comment: Got the same error with Caliburn.Micro in Release when deploying to Device.

Comment: Are you seeing this deployment issue only in that particular project, or in all projects created that use the Band SDK?  On which version(s) of Visual Studio? I tried to reproduce the issue with a new Windows Phone 8.1 application, in Visual Studio 2013, using the latest Band SDK (v1.3.10417.1) and was able to successfully deploy the application regardless of Configuration or Platform.

Comment: Hi Lance, please do not add solutions to the question, please answer your question and accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Bummi, thank you, I'll do that now. I thought it was frowned upon to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the solution still had the old **Band SDK - Preview** packages even after updating to the newer SDK. I manually deleted all the nuget items, forced a package refresh and the project now deploys successfully.

Here are the steps:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Navigate to **YourSolution/Packages/**
3. Delete everything *except* **packages.config**
4. Reopen the solution in Visual Studio
5. Right click on solution and select "**Manage Nuget Packages**"
6. Click the "**Restore**" button that appears at the top of the dialog window

Rebuild the solution and it should deploy properly